# Excel, if values being entered into a specific column equals any value from column x in sheet 2 throw an error

Tags: excel, if-statement

Please assist me on this one.

Excel, if values being entered into a specific column (e.g. col A in sheet 1) equals any value from column B in sheet 2 throw an error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this formula in a cell. It will return "Error", if the value of A1 is found anywhere in column B of sheet 2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!B1:B10000,A1)>0, "Error", "No Error")
```

If you want the cell to be blank if the value is not found in column B of sheet 2, use the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!B1:B10000,A1)>0, "Error", "")
```

Comment: brother where do i put this formula in ? I selected A column and put the formula in data validation > custom, but it is throwing an Excel error on any value

Comment: Select cell B1 of sheet 1, and paste the formula into that cell. Then if you put a value in cell A1 of sheet 1, and put the same value anywhere in column B of sheet 2, cell A2 will display "Error".

Comment: This is not using data validation.

Comment: I already have some values in Sheet 2 , column B in multiple cells, what i want to do is, if I enter any value in any cell in Column A , Sheet 1 , it should check if the value exists in any cell in Sheet 2 column B and throw an error if True else do nothing

Comment: Ok. This is a solution to that question. Find an empty column in sheet 1, and copy this formula into the first cell of that column, and copy it down the column so that every cell contains the formula:

`=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!B$1:B$10000,A1)>0, "Error", "")` 

Now when you enter any value in column A it will check if it exists in column B of sheet 2, and display "Error" in the column with this formula.

Comment: thanks bro .. got it now ...its working ... is there anything you know what would pop up an error instead of in the cell, or not allow that value to be entered ?

Comment: I'll have a look into it. Haven't done much with data validation - will let you know.

Comment: @Manu Try this - in the data validation menu, select custom, and put this formula in: `=ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!B:B,0))`, and create your on error message in the error tab.